# How to use Send Dialog to post to friends wall?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

In the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) for the 'Send' dialog, it says

> ... They’ll have the option to privately share a link as a Facebook message, Group post or email.

I've been testing this method but no option shows.  It only seems to send a message.  Is there a parameter or something I'm missing?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a group post or email, you just type the group name or email address in the "To" field of the send dialog (try [here](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=123050457758183&name=People%20Argue%20Just%20to%20Win&link=http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response)). It sounds like you might be asking the wrong question...what exactly are you trying to achieve?

edit: after re-reading the title of your post, you cant post to someone's wall with the send dialog. The send dialog will send a link to their messages, not to their wall. If you want to put a link or something on a friend's wall, you need the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), and to specify a 'to' parameter